# Is K-2 cross-validation essentially equal to train-test split of 50:50?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, train-test-split

I am working on an data project assignment where I am asked to use 50% of data for training and remaining 50% of data for testing. I would like to use the magic of cross-validation and still meet the aforementioned criteria.

Currently, my code is following:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', class_weight='balanced'

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

#cross validation
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
i = 0
for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    probas_ = clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    i += 1

print("Average AUC: ", sum(aucs)/len(aucs),"AUC: ", aucs[-1],)
```

Since I am using just 2 splits, is it considered as if I was using train-test split of 50:50? Or should I first split data into 50:50 and then use cross validation on the training part, and finally use that model to test the remaining 50% on test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your second suggestion. 
Cross-validation should be used to tune the parameters of your approach. Among others, such parameters in your example are the value of the `C` parameter and the `class_weight='balanced'`  of Logistic Regression. So you should:

- split in 50% training, 50% test
- use the training data to select the optimal values of the parameters of your model with cross-validation
- Refit the model with the optimal parameters on the training data
- Predict for the test data and report the score of the evaluation measure you selected

Notice, you should use the test data **only** for reporting the final score and not for tuning the model, otherwise you are cheating. Imagine, that in reality you may not have access to them until the last moment, so you can not use them.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. In case you have time, could you give me an insight on the following error that I am getting when I split data? My code is following https://gist.github.com/mkondela/c3c077829b210b2b6439011ab07be3ee

Comment: No problem, I gave you the upvote but it doesn't show up since I don't have sufficient reputation yet.

Comment: No worries. Your error suggests that there are NaNs. Maybe caused by missing values in the training data. Check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html to spot the NaN and trace backwards to see why they occurred.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the np.isnan, and it shows that some of the y_train are False and some True. Before passing y_train to `for train, test in cv.split(X_train, y_train): ` y_train is clearly consisting of 1s, and 0s. However, inside the loop when indexing through y_train some values are 0, some are 1, and some are NaNs. I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: Ok I have solved it. If anyone has the same problem, solution is to use iloc method on y_train. Code should be following y_train.iloc[index]